# passing html input value into jquery ui dialog ass variable

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, input, dialog

I have a html form with an autocomplete input field that open an jquery dialog.
in this dialog i have an sql search that will need the value from the input box.
How can i get the input in the Dialog box ass variable?

```
<!--autocomplete script -->
 <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#searchImage" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1 
      });
   });
</script>

<!-- Dialog Script -->
          <script>    $(function(){       
     $('#imageDialog').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       bgiframe: true,
       height: "auto",
       width: 900,
       modal: true,
       position: [ "center" , 150],
       show: {
          effect: "clip",
          duration: 1000
       },
       hide: {
          effect: "clip",
          duration: 1000
       },
       buttons: {
          OK: function() { 
              $(this).dialog( "close" ); 
          }
       }
     });

     $('form#imageForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#imageDialog').dialog('open');
     });
    });
  </script>

<!-- Search Box -->
   <div class="partSearch">
   <form id="imageForm" name="imageForm" method="get">
   <label for="image"><b>Image: </b></label>
   <input id="searchImage" name="searchImage" type="text" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </form>

<!-- Dialog Content -->
   <div id="imageDialog" title="Image">
     <?php
     <Code to get the Image name from input>;
     //DB query
     $query="select image, ssid, to_char(savetime,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') savetime, path
             from table
             where image like upper('%$IMAGE%')
             order by image asc, savetime desc";    
     ?>
```

Comment: Ok? so what problem do you have.

Comment: You haven't stated a question, @Jérôme!

Comment: I like to find a way to get the input value ass php variable

Comment: @Jérôme, you would have to pass the value to the server.  You can't assign values to PHP variables on the client side.

Comment: @Derek How can i do pass the variable to the server and calling it on the samne page?

Answer (score 0):

try to look at [jQuery UI autoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and and instead of using php directly use a AJAX call that will populate the array used in autocomplete plugin

```
 <script>
$(function() {

   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source:  myarray ;  // here put your values from ajax call 
   });
});
</script>
```

And so you will get the value from input with jQuery.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but i have no ajax knowledge :(
Here is my autocomplete function:

$(function() {
        $( "#searchImage" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 1 
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

in your "search.php" you execute a method and in that method you have to do your search to database an the result to send it as a JSON array to te ajax call.

```
function searchInDB($param) {

    // php code

    return json_encode($sql_result_from_search);
}


<?php
    echo json_encode(array("test","test","test"));
    echo json_encode(array(0=>"test",3=>"test",7=>"test"));
?>

Will give :

["test","test","test"]
{"0":"test","3":"test","7":"test"}
```

You have to read more about AJAX. take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)